# JavaScript - Is it possible to get height from div in separate page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering, is it possible to collect the height of a specific div container from a separate page with JavaScript? I'm using jQuery btw and I'm in need of comparing heights of div containers.

Edit: To clarify a bit more, I load content from a specific div in a separate page using jQuery. This content is faded into a different container with dynamic height. But in the small fraction of time before the content arrives, it shrinks down to it's min-height.

What I've done so far is collecting the height of the container before and after the load. But it only works after I've loaded content once. Because I don't have the height before it's been loaded the first time.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate page"?

Comment: Ah, Sorry, I typed wrong in the title and read wrong right here :p
I've got two pages (php files) which both contain a div container with the same ID. I use a script that collects th content from this div and inserts it into the same container of my currently loaded page. I need to compare the height of this container before it's been loaded with the height of my current div container. :)

Comment: I guess this small edit doesn't help us ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship between the pages is opener and [popup|child] window, then yes.

***If not, you are going to run into a security wall. (unrelated pages should not have access to each other)***

So, if the "other" page is a popup window that your page launched, or a child iframe that your page "launched", then yes.

I would use the jQuery .height() method to obtain the height, but how you get the object is up to you (depends on what attribute info you have etc.)

```
//get from popup
var otherDiv = popupWinRef.document.getElementbyId('id');

//get from iframe
var otherDiv = window.frames[frameIdOrIndex].document.getElementById('id');

alert($(otherDiv).height());
```

Comment: Yeah, it's not from a popup or nothing. Just from a separate page. Guess it can't be done since that page haven't even been rendered yet, thus you cannot collect any height since there is none :)

Comment: @Kenny - yeah it sounds like this fails on 2 counts. 1.) Security-wise you have no access to "some other page" that wasn't created by you, or that created you. 2.) If you did have access - you would need to get the height info after it rendered as it likely isn't correctly known until it has fully rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't get it until AFTER it's loaded via jQuery. Then you need to make sure you're not having a conflict between two divs with the same ID.

Comment: Yes, well strangely enough, after the first load, the loader loads the entire content of said div including the div itself. Resulting in a div with another div in it, both with the same ID. This actually happens in the original plugin as well. I haven't encountered any problems yet though.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds like you are using ajax to load content from another page, you'll likely have the load div hidden... So I would position the loading div absolutely out of the viewport but not hidden. then get the height of your desired div but make sure you access it using the loading div and your desired div... something like this:

```
#divToLoadContent { position: absolute; left: -99999em; top: 0; } /* don't hide this div */
```

Script

```
var height = $('#divToLoadContent #myDesiredDiv').height();
```